# Which LAPACK routine should I use if I only want to compute the eigenvectors?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, generalized-eigenvector

Assume that you are having two types of matrices: $A$ and $B$.
They both are symmetric.

Which fastest LAPACK routine should I use if I ***only*** want to compute the eigenvectors $v$ from the generalized eigenvalue problem?

$$Av = \lambda B v$$